# Где можно найти копии веб-страниц, которые загружаются с сервера

Tags: веб-сервер

Тут - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/How_the_Web_works - написано, что при переходе на какую-то веб страницу, ее копия загружается с сервера на клиентский компьютер для отображения. У меня вопрос, где я могу найти это копию на своем компьютере?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, нельзя буквально понимать загрузку как создание копии страницы в виде, в котором её можно найти на компьютере.

Думаю, что имеется в виду, что эта "копия" существует в виде данных в памяти процесса "веб браузер", занимающегося отображением страницы.

Вообще говоря, страница устроена сложнее: она состоит из множества ресурсов, которые также загружаются с разных сервером (js, картинки, css).

И некоторые из этих ресурсов - например, картинки - можно найти в кеше браузера. (Кеш в разных браузерах устроен по разному, но в общем картинку найти в кеше браузера - это реально.)

Также, есть старый способ: можно нажать в браузере клавиши Ctrl+S - и появится диалог сохранения файла. Так можно искусственно создать копию страницы в виде файла на своём компьютере.